# Using lists in functions in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am not able to understand what is happening in the code below

```
#swaps list in index 1
L=[[1,2],[3,4]]
def swap(X):
  beta=X[:]
  beta[1][0],beta[1][1]=beta[1][1],beta[1][0]
  return beta
def code(W):
  alpha=W[:]
  print swap(alpha)
  return swap(alpha)
print code(L)
```

It gives an output

```
[[1, 2], [4, 3]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

While i am expecting

```
[[1, 2], [4, 3]]
[[1, 2], [4, 3]]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for that is that

```
alpha = W[:]    # and also beta=X[:]
```

only create a **shallow copy** of the list. This means that only the **outer** list is actually copied. This outer list then again contains references to more lists - these lists are in not copied (*only the references to them*).

So your copies `alpha` and `beta` are always referring to the **same** nested lists and swapping the elements in these lists. This is why you can see the swapping happen twice after calling

```
swap(alpha)
```

twice.

If you want to make a deep copy you can use the `copy` module and write

```
alpha = copy.deepcopy(W)   # instead of alpha = W[:]
```

and

```
beta= copy.deepcopy(X)     # instead of beta = X[:]
```

Doing this will give you your expected output:

```
[[1, 2], [4, 3]]
[[1, 2], [4, 3]]
```